# How to handle System.DBNull?

Tags: c#, dbnull

I have a object with type:

```
dynamic {System.DBNull}
```

I want to check it:

```
if (myObject!= null || myObject!= DBNull.Value)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Oh hi");
}
```

But the `MessageBox` always appears. Whats wrong, is it another type?

Comment: I think: messagebox always appears but shouldn't be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression is always true

```
myObject != null || myObject != DBNull.Value
```

because `myObject` cannot be `null` and `DBNull.Value` at the same time. Replace `||` with `&&` to fix.

Comment: this didn't work for me - myObject (which I had as dynamic) was a `DateTime` type - I was getting errors about how I can't use `!=` on objects of different types...  Had to go with `!Convert.IsDBNull(myObject)` (Kjartan's answer)

Answer (score 2):

There is also a function for checking for DBNull:

```
if(myObject != null && !Convert.IsDBNull(myObject))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Oh hi");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
if(myObject != DBNull.Value)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Oh hi");
}
```

or

```
if(myObject != null && myObject != DBNull.Value)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Oh hi");
}
```